# Dialog closes automatically after opening with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am modifying this [example](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/) I found about creating modals.

I want to use javascript for showing the dialog.
The code I have it opens me the dialog, but it closes after 1 or 2 seconds. Checking the console I'm not getting no error.

This is the html code.
I have a jsbin where you can observe the dialog closing automatically. http://jsbin.com/UDIGeveg/1/edit

```
<body>
    <a id="openModal" href="">Open Modal</a>
    <div id="openM" class="modalDialog">
        <div>
            <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
            <h2>Modal Box</h2>
            <p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>   
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my javascript

```
$('#' +"openModal").click(function(){
  document.location.href='#'+"openM";
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`$('#' + "openModal")` is an anchor tag and it's default action is to direct you to another link.
So you need to prevent its default action from being triggered by using [e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$('#' +"openModal").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  document.location.href='#'+"openM";
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I was going to ask you what does e.preventDefault() does.

Comment: An alternative to `e.preventDefault();` is set the anchor href attribute as `href='javascript:;'`, in order to make the link do nothing on click.

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez that would be the way to go if you wanted to have a completely js-free dialog

Answer (score 0):

you can use the library to detect the url change for you!

```
<a id="openModal" href="#openM">Open Modal</a>
```

and then comment out your javascript:

```
/*
$('#' +"openModal").click(function(){
    document.location.href='#'+"openM";
});
*/
```

Comment: I know thta. But planning to do more things with javascript.